# Как в Laravel 5 присвоить свои значения для полей таблицы

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Как в Laravel 5 присвоить свои значения для полей таблицы в модели?

Например как в `Yii2` можно присвоить свои значения для полей таблицы через функцию `getAttributeLabel()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете `FormRequest` для валидации, то создайте метод с названием `attributes` и дальше всё аналогично как в Yii:

```
public function attributes()
{
    return [
      'name' => 'Name'  
    ];
}
```

Если же используете просто валидатор, то нужно использовать метод `setAttributes`:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
$names = [
    'name' => 'Name'
];
$validator->setAttributeNames($names);
```

В самой модели указать нельзя, потому что валидаторы и модели в Laravel не так реализованы как в Yii.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение, то что нужно!